# Big O Of Mod 20

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

What is the big O of this code?

```
def mod20(n):
    return n%20
```

Is it logarithmic linear?

Can you describe to me a example for all the big O?

Comment: What do you expect to gain from the answer if you don't know what it means?

Comment: It doesn't even make sense to ask that question. The size of your input is always 1. Big O describes how speed changes with input size.

Comment: A number between 0 and 19. No, just kidding, thats the result of the operation. The complexity of that operation is obviously constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can insert integers of **any** size, the complexity will be the same as the complexity of division.

So it is `O(log n)` due to `log n` is the number of digits.

*Notice 1*: If you can only insert 32 or 64 bit integers, the "complexity" will be `O(1)`.

*Notice 2*: Since computers save all numbers in binary, you can get `n % 2^k` in konstant time, even if `n` can be of any size. You just take the `k` smalest bits. This dont work for `n % 20` without computing the representation of `n` to the base 20.

If you want to know what Big-O means, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/3440545) will help you.